# Left Join problem with where AND

Tags: sql, sqlite

Here is some hardcoded syntax. IPAddr is an int, this is sqlite and will be ported to mysql.

The syntax doesnt work with `AND V.IPAddr <> 0`. Possibly because V is a left join and may not exist (null?). How do I get it to to succeed when `V == null || V.IPAddr <> Val`?

```
select Post.id, name, body,
      (select count() from Votes where id=Post.id AND (type & 4)<> 0) as DV
   from Post 
left join Votes as V on V.id=Post.id
   where flag='1'  AND V.IPAddr <> 0 AND DV<1
   limit 1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move the outer filter to the JOIN condition. Otherwise, the filter changes it to a INNER JOIN

```
select Post.id, name, body,
(select count() from Votes where id=Post.id AND (type & 4)<> 0) as DV
from Post 
left join Votes as V on V.id=Post.id AND V.IPAddr <> 0 
where flag='1' AND DV<1
limit 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Gbn's solution is the best, but here are two other solutions.  You can use a subquery:

```
from      Post p
left join (
          select  *
          from    Votes
          where   IPAddr <> 0
          ) v
on        v.id = p.id
```

Or an improved where clause:

```
from      Post p
left join Votes v
on        v.id = p.id
where     (IPAddr <> 0 or IPAddr is null)
```